# Why LESS css width results in MORE visual width?

Tags: css

I have an html like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
body { background-color: #eee; }

.container {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 1.5em 0;
 }

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cell">Left cell</div>
    <div class="cell">#</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and I'm baffled with the `width` property. The value `10%` produces **more** visual width than value `50%`. Why?

NOTE: I deliberately miss out css `width` property for `.container`, so to observe how/why CSS behaves this way.

See image below:

[image]

## # # # # # #

[image]

## # # # # # #

[image]

Comment: A table is by default as wide as it's contents. In your case this creates the following scenario: cell says "I'm 50% width of you, table. So how much is that for me?". table responds "Well, that depends on how wide you two are, because I'm just as wide as necessary to include you both. So how wide are you?" cell says: "I'm 50% width of you, table. So how much is that for me?" .... rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your container's `display: table` style. It's unwise to mix table structure along with its cells' individual width property.
So, either use `div layout` or control the width of cell's from your `container`'s `style.width` property.
Please note, typical table style maintain's its cell's width ratio in its own way.
Also, I will suggest to add a `width` property to your `container`. Then you can play with `cell`'s `style.width` and see for yourself how `table`s work.

Comment: Oh yes. If I add `width:100%` to `.container`, the cells `width` value becomes rational. But I'd like to know, in case of lacking the container's `width` value, what is the rule to determine the cell's visual width.

Comment: I believe its the cell's content, like @connexo commented